# Remote main water shut off & drain valves in crawl space winterizing

Tags: plumbing, water, valve, shutoff

Want to be able to shut off main water line in crawl space off via a switch inside and also want to install another valve right above to drain the lines for winter protection while gone and possibly another valve to pump in rv antifreeze into system, 3 story house with 4 bathrooms. Have been doing this manually in a walk in basement on another house for years but it's a difficult crawl at this house and I'm getting too old to do so!

So thoughts? Thinking will add 3 110v SPST switches located in house, but can use relays to motorized valves if necessary.

My ideal scenario:

- Flip 1st switch 1st valve shuts off main water supply in crawlspace via motorized valve.
- Flip 2nd switch & 2nd motorized valve just above it opens to drain out lines in house, then flip it back to close.
- Flip 3rd switch & 3rd motorized valve above 2nd opens to pump in rv antifreeze then flip back to close when filled. I'll run a line from portable antifreeze pump inside house to a T there.

Trying to do as cost effective as possible and prefer to stay away from wifi type dependent valves. I see lots of NO or NC 3/4'' motorized valves but they require continuous power to stay open or closed so not a option. unless using a step down transformer. So is this where relays and transformers come into play? I'm a plumber and electrician so prefer to stay with what I am familiar with being no transformers or relays if possible. Someone recommended to possibly use irrigation valves? Been searching for hours and can't find much. Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is mostly a shopping question, which would be off-topic here. That said, my guess is that the effort to install such a system would be far greater than years of using the existing valves.